# How to use autocomplete with method of class

Tags: pyqt4, qscintilla

I cannot found how to use autocomplete for methods/properties from class.

I'm using [add()](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciAPIs.html#af46ca05571eb676d3aa65b080fb406c5) for add string, but I cannot think how it can work with classes. Any one know?

Edit 1

I'm using it for funciontion

```
api = Qsci.QsciAPIs(lexer)
api.add("myfunction1")
api.add("myfunction2")
api.add("myfunction3")
api.prepare()
```

I need to complete methods of some class, for sample

myclass1
myclass1->method1
myclass1->method2

myclass2
myclass2->method1
myclass2->method3

I want to write *myclass2->* and autocomplete method1, method3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the format used when adding entries programmatically is the same as the one used in API files.

API file entries look like this:

```
PyQt4.QtGui.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding?10
PyQt4.QtGui.QTabWidget.addTab?4(QWidget, str) -> int
PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant.toInt?4() -> (int, bool)
PyQt4.phonon.Phonon.createPlayer?4(Phonon.Category, Phonon.MediaSource source=Phonon.MediaSource()) -> Phonon.MediaObject
PyQt4.QtCore.QObject.findChildren?4(tuple, str name='') -> list-of-QObject
```

So, the format seems to be:

- namespaces are separated by dots
- a namespace can be followed by `?n`, where `n` indicates an identifier to be used when [registering associated images](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciScintilla.html#a38bf5a8680df52675e5299fccbbc7181)
- the function/method signature is a comma-separated list of types in parentheses
- the return type is indicated by `->` followed by either a type, or a comma-separated list of types in parentheses

The last three items are probably all optional (the last two are only used for call-tips).

Comment: Sorry, I think you not understand my question, or I not understand your answer. Adding this format, the autocomplete got all string added. [link](http://files.primeseven.com.br/view/5431a2e5bd40c9/51861005) I need complete only method, after write all class, not all string

Comment: I certainly did understand. Like I said in my answer, you need to separate all namespaces with **dots**. To test, copy the examples in my answer **exactly**. You've replaced some of the dots with `->`, which is not the correct format.

Comment: I've just noticed in that image that your function is called `phpAutocomplete`. You did not mention anywhere that you were trying to implement **php** autocompletion! I assumed you were trying to do **python** autocompletion. If you use `QsciLexerPython`, my example will work. However, there is currently no "QsciLexerPHP", so what lexer are you using?

Comment: I'm using QsciLexerCPP. Where did you find this doc? I'll try with LexerPython to see if it's work

Comment: that's really work man. I'm glad to know that's possible. I'll search more about this patterns

Comment: QScintilla docs are [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/annotated.html). You might also be interested in the Scintilla docs, which are [here](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html).